# Can someone suggest a good image cache library?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

I am using this one https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache but it has some bugs and I don't really want to search to fixing them. Are there other alternatives?

Basically I need to cache images from web.

Comment: fixing bugs is the best way to become a better coder...

Comment: What all you have tried till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [EGOImageLoading](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading)  by enormego for caching images.
It Works just like UIImageView and lets you download images from HTTP asynchronously.